# Wanting to mix server side ASP.Net MVC expansion in javascript file, but how... RenderPartial?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have some common javascript functionality that I want to share across several views/pages.

However I want to put some C#/ASP.net into the javascript - pulling in some data from the server.

It seems like the best option is to use a partial page, and include the javascript in that.

Just wondering if there is a javascript equivalent of the partial page?

Or is there another/better/alternative way of doing this?

EDIT:
I realise I could use ajax to pull the server code in (although how do I refer to the server, Url.Content won't work) but this code is to handle page permissions, ie the server data details what functions the user can access and the javascript functions are then used to show/hide buttons based on that.  So the data needs to be present early on rather than triggering the page to be built after the ajax callback happens.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Do you want to use view model values in the javascript?

Comment: That would be one way, although as its going to be shared across several views, I am thinking a HtmlHelper is more appropriate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually put some data that is needed by javascript into the top of the page.

I have it in the Masterpage.

After that I include the common js files. The variables defined at the top of page are available to the scripts.
Don't forget to JavascriptEncode these values. Html-Encode is not enough, it doesn't handle the '. Use Web Protection Library for it http://wpl.codeplex.com/.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var controller = <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(ViewContext.RouteValues.GetRequiredString("controller")) %>;
var userRightRead = <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Model.UserRightRead) %>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> However I want to put some C#/ASP.net
>   into the javascript - pulling in some
>   data from the server

You don't need to put any C#/ASP.NET into javascript to pull data from the server. You can simply use AJAX. Example with [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/someaction',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good point, I have clarified the question as to why I am doing it this way.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. Why would you want to refer to the server (for example `Url.Content`) in a javascript file?

Comment: In your example, the url '/home/someaction' is an absolute url on the current server - what if the webapp is under the root /mywebapp - Url.Content sorts that out, as I understand it.

Comment: In this case you could declare a global variable `var url = '<%= Url.Action("someAction") %>';` in your view which you could use in the jqvqscript file. Or simply use an anchor `<%= Html.ActionLink("some text", "someAction") %>` that you can ajaxify.

Answer (score 1):

I'll normally wrap the javascript up in a class and then pass in the view model values I need.

For example with this javascript:

```
var testClass = function(config){
    this.width = config.width;
    this.height = config.height; 

    this.showDimensions = function(){ 
        alert( this.width + " by " + this.height); 
    }
}
```

the view/partial view would contain:

```
<script>
var dim = new testClass({ 
    width: <%=Model.Width %>
    height: <%=Model.Height %>
})

dim.showDimensions();
</script>
```